# Alternative to panels - to see all the panels easier

Tags: c#

When I create a Visual App with 3 panels, I can only see the panel that is in the front, and can't see how other panels look and work, only after I run the app itself.

I want to see different panels in the builder directly. 
Is there any alternative to panels?

I only know about the Panels for now, I'm just starting.

I expect to have a menu where I can click on Panel 3 for example and see only that panel and it's components. 
Now, if I have 7 panels, and panel7 is on top, I can only edit panel7 elements.. and the others are hidden.

Comment: Sounds to me as if you want to be using UserControls ( [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8), [WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8) ) instead of panels directly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: Have you tried pressing Control+Tab to cycle between the panels?  It's possible that ALT+F6 might work too.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: There are several alternatives to plain Panels but they all share the issue you are facing. - You could place them apart and only align them when the form opens. note that placing panel on top of each other with the mouse tends to nest them and will pose other problems as well. You could place them in a invisible tab  control and move them out and back in at runtime..